# How can I ensure Django CMS initializes app urls?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I'm trying to boot up a Django CMS app. All the app hooks are properly set up and registered. For an example take the `NewsHook`:

```py
class NewsHook(CMSApp):
    """ A class to hook the News into the django cms
    """
    name = ("News")
    urls = ["apps.news.urls"]


apphook_pool.register(NewsHook)
```

The `urls.py` of this hook includes the following:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # /feed/
    url(r'^feed/$', ArticlesFeed(), name='news_feed'),
]
```

And the `urls.py` of the project (under the `settings` folder) includes the following relevant lines:

```
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    ...
    # / -> Django CMS
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)
```

All this looks normal, right? But when I visit the home page, I get `NoReverseMatch` error:

[image]

Not sure what I am doing wrong... Is there a side of this that I'm not seeing? Btw, this app runs well on production, so it doesn't have any bugs as far as I can see.

### My Specs

- Django version: 1.8.13
- Django CMS version: 3.3.0
- Python version: 2.7.

Comment: Can you post the complete error stack and the file `cms.urls`? NoReverseMatch simply means that url is not found in your complete list of urls. For the homepage this would be the urls described the file `cms.urls`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that these Django CMS apps need to be attached to a page in order to add the urls to the project. I loaded the pages table from the production and the urls started functioning.

Making the urls dependent on the presence of a page is really counterintuitive to me, coming from Rails.